# Write a program that adds together all the numbers between 0 and 100. Print the result

Tags: loops, for-loop, processing

I want to write a program that adds all the numbers between 0 and 100 but my code does not add everything correctly. How do I add the next number to the number and then print the sum?

This is the code I have:

```
         for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
           i+=i;
           println(i);
         }
```

The result of this shows 0, 2, 6, 14... and I need the sum of all the numbers 1 through 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting this odd result is that you add those numbers to i  instead of having a dedicated collector.

```
int collector = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
       collector += i;
       println(collector);
}
```

If you only want to print the sum once, move the println(collector) expression outside the loop.

There is also a mathematical formula to directly compute the sum of the first n numbers

```
Sum(1, n) = n * (n+1) / 2
```

In Processing:

```
int Sum(int n){
  return n * (n + 1) / 2;
}
```

The [formula works](https://web.archive.org/web/20171225182632/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/57919.html) because the numbers 1 to N can be rearranged and added like this:

```
 (1 + N) + (2 + N-1) + (3 + N-2) + . . . . + (N + N/2+1) = total
```

for N = 100:

```
 (1 + 100) + (2 + 99) + (3 + 98) + . . . . + (50 + 51) = 5050
   101     +   101    +   101    + . . . . +    101    = 5050
```